# Generate URL from hook_menu() pattern

Tags: routes

Does Drupal have any tool to generate URL from hook_menu() link pattern? Something like this:

```
some_function('node/%/edit/something/%', array(1, 19))
```

that will generate this URL: `http://maindomain.com/node/1/edit/something/19`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Drupal has a function for that specific case - at least not one that I've come across.

Obviously lots of ways to accomplish it though. Without writing your own function, my thought was to make use of the [`format_string()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/format_string/7) and [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) functions.

```
$args = array(
  '@arg_1' => 1,
  '@arg_4' => 19,
);
$path = format_string('node/@arg_1/edit/something/%arg_4', $args);
$url = url($path, array('absolute' => TRUE)); // I used absolute here because
                                              // your example has an absolute
                                              // path. It shouldn't be
                                              // necessary though.
print $url // Prints `http[s]:[domain.com]/[base_path]/node/1/edit/something/19`
```

Of course, you could take that a step further and use the [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function to create an actual link, but I'm not sure what your exact use case is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;). Everything is ok, but the arguments in the pattern are the same and I'm taking them from hook_menu() keys. So it's like `link/%/part1/%/something`. I think, that I must write my own function..